# Can I make a short visit to Germany on a transit visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I’m a permanent resident (Green Card holder) in the USA and I’m flying to Jordan through Frankfurt. If I would like to enter Germany for a short visit, maximum 7-8 days, can I apply for a transit visa that allows me to enter Germany or do I have to apply for a Schengen visa?

Comment: Transit visa does not allow you to leave the airport. And visiting for 7-8 days is in no way a transit.

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: Schengen wants to know your nationality, residence permits are totally irrelevant. These include the *precious* US Green Cards issued by lotteries. You will use your US Green Card to re-enter the US after your visit to Jordan

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments, what you plan (7-8 days) is not a transit. Holding a green card itself doesn't allow you to enter the Schengen area without a visa, so it's up to your nationality. In [this document](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32018R1806&from=EN) you can find a list of all countries whose nationals are required to be in possession of a visa. [Europe.eu](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy_en) also shows an interactive map where you can see if you need a visa or not.